# Generating quartiles from an imputed variable

Tags: multiple-imputation

I am using Multiple Imputation to impute a continuous variable (`X`). I have a question regarding the generation of a new variable, starting from this imputed variable (what, in Stata jargon, would be called a *passive variable*).

In particular, my aim is to divide this variable `X` into, say, quartiles. Let's suppose that I imputed this variable $n$ times (`X_1, ..., X_n`). What am I supposed to do?

Should I create the quartiles "independently" for each of the $n$ imputations? In this case the cut-offs of the quartiles (i.e. the 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles) wouldn't be the same across the $n$ *passive* variables I created.

Should I pool the $n$ imputations, calculate the 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles and use those numbers to divide my $n$ imputed variables into quartiles?

Comment: You should pool the $n$ imputations but more important part of MI is the number of imputations, $n$. If I remember correctly, you need to impute at least 40 times with 50% missing information to guarantee less than 1% power falloff compared to the comparable full-information maximum likelihood analysis. This [paper](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~snijders/Graham2009.pdf) should be helpful.